# Latest Wifi Update not working

Tags: wireless, updates

I installed Ubuntu at the start of the month, wifi sucked, updated everything was fine.

Last week the most recent wifi update that came out last week or like 5 days ago made my internet not work again, it cuts off and on every once in a while, I stream a video site and it starts cutting off and on and my speed test shows like .01 kbs sometimes

I have an Airlink 101 150N AWLL6070

What's annoying is last week it worked fine, then I installed the wireless update and bam it messed up.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried installing any drivers?

Comment: I don't think any linux drivers exist for my usb device

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi update"?

Comment: It was an update that said wireless or something like that, is their a way to check what it was?

Comment: just saw it was one that said Networking update I think.